# Knockout computed only firing once

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a feeling that this isn't going to be a simple problem (or may be associated with something entirely un-related) but I'm going to take a shot. I have an ASP.NET MVC page that also uses KnockOutJS. There are two related drop-downs on the page. The first one presents a list of Offer Types. Depending on which Offer Type you choose, the second drop-down needs to re-populate with the correct options for that Offer Type.

This used to work at some point in time, but the page is under heavy construction and now not working. **When I select a new Offer Type, the other dropdown doesn't repopulate.**

Here is the HTML for the DropDowns. You'll notice there is a hidden input there. **When I select a new OfferType, this correctly populates with the OfferTypeId.**

```
<div class="control-group" style="clear: both;">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OfferType, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        <select class="input-block-level" id="OfferType" name="OfferType" data-bind="options: offerTypes, value: selectedOfferType, optionsText: 'DisplayName'"></select>
    </div>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OfferTypeId, new { data_bind = "value: selectedOfferType().OfferTypeId" })
</div>

<div class="control-group" style="clear: both;">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OfferTypeDetails, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        <select class="input-block-level" id="OfferTypeDetails" name="OfferTypeDetails" data-bind="options: offerDetails, value: selectedOffer, optionsText: 'DisplayName'"></select>
    </div>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OfferTypeDetailsTypeId, new { data_bind = "value: selectedOffer().OfferTypeId" })
</div>
```

And here is the Javascript (data trimmed for brevity):

```
       $(document).ready(function () {              
            var offerType = function (offerTypeId, displayName, offerTypeDetailsTypes) {
                var self = this;
                self.OfferTypeId = offerTypeId;
                self.DisplayName = displayName;
                self.OfferTypeDetailsTypes = offerTypeDetailsTypes;
            };

            var offerTypeDetailsType = function (offerTypeDetailsTypeId, displayName, offerTypeId) {
                var self = this;
                self.OfferTypeDetailsTypeId = offerTypeDetailsTypeId;
                self.DisplayName = displayName;
                self.OfferTypeId = offerTypeId;
            };  

            function viewModel() {
                var self = this;

                self.selectedOfferType = ko.observable();
                self.selectedOffer = ko.observable();

                self.offerTypes = ko.observableArray([
                    new offerType('1', 'Purchase Discount'),
                    new offerType('2', 'Savings'),
                    ...
                ]);

                self.offerTypeDetailsTypes = ko.observableArray([
                    new offerTypeDetailsType('1', 'Spend $10  Get $1 Off', '1'),
                    new offerTypeDetailsType('2', 'Spend $100  Get 10% Off', '1'),
                    new offerTypeDetailsType('3', '$ Half Off', '2'),
                    ...
                ]);         

                self.offerDetails = ko.computed({
                    read: function () {
                        var activeCategories = ko.observableArray();
                        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.offerTypeDetailsTypes(), function (item) {
                            if (item.OfferTypeId == self.selectedOfferType().OfferTypeId)
                                activeCategories.push(item);
                        });
                        return activeCategories();
                    } , deferEvaluation: true
                });         
            }
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());  
        }
```

Comment: Quick comment Todd: in offerDetails your activeCategories doesn't need to be an observableArray.  A simple JavaScript array would suffice.  Also you can filter using ko.utils.arrayFilter rather than arrayForEach. http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that was helpful, and certainly a lot less code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todd, I was able to get your example code working without any problems.  I just coppied to jsFiddle and remove the MVC Razor and jquery stuff.

http://jsfiddle.net/zrDtU/

The html

```
<select class="input-block-level" id="OfferType" name="OfferType" data-bind="options: offerTypes, value: selectedOfferType, optionsText: 'DisplayName'"></select>

<select class="input-block-level" id="OfferTypeDetails" name="OfferTypeDetails" data-bind="options: offerDetails, value: selectedOffer, optionsText: 'DisplayName'"></select>
```

The javascript

```
//I can't post a link to jsFiddle without code
var offerType = function (offerTypeId, displayName, offerTypeDetailsTypes) {
    var self = this;
    self.OfferTypeId = offerTypeId;
    self.DisplayName = displayName;
    self.OfferTypeDetailsTypes = offerTypeDetailsTypes;
};

var offerTypeDetailsType = function (offerTypeDetailsTypeId, displayName, offerTypeId) {
    var self = this;
    self.OfferTypeDetailsTypeId = offerTypeDetailsTypeId;
    self.DisplayName = displayName;
    self.OfferTypeId = offerTypeId;
};

function viewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.selectedOfferType = ko.observable();
    self.selectedOffer = ko.observable();

    self.offerTypes = ko.observableArray([
        new offerType('1', 'Purchase Discount'),
        new offerType('2', 'Savings')
    ]);

    self.offerTypeDetailsTypes = ko.observableArray([
        new offerTypeDetailsType('1', 'Spend $10  Get $1 Off', '1'),
        new offerTypeDetailsType('2', 'Spend $100  Get 10% Off', '1'),
        new offerTypeDetailsType('3', '$ Half Off', '2')
    ]);

    self.offerDetails = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            var activeCategories = ko.observableArray();
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.offerTypeDetailsTypes(), function (item) {
                if (item.OfferTypeId == self.selectedOfferType().OfferTypeId) activeCategories.push(item);
            });
            return activeCategories();
        },
        deferEvaluation: true
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

It looks like your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Yup, it was, but thank you for making the effort. There was some errant JavaScript, and it was almost by accident that I found it in the end. I'm still not sure why it was breaking just this one thing in this one place, but then again, I'm just happy it is working now.